# Are 3 or more times overlapping C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to determine whether times ranges are overlapping on a CRUD page but am stuck.

I can get it working with two time ranges using the code below but I need it working for 3 as well.

```
public static bool IsOverLapping(ConfigureViewModel viewModel)
{
    bool status = false;
    var times = viewModel.Periods.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime.TimeOfDay).ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i <= times.Count - 2; i++)
    {
        if (times[i].StartTime.TimeOfDay <= times[i + 1].EndTime.TimeOfDay)
        {
            if (times[i + 1].StartTime.TimeOfDay >= times[i].EndTime.TimeOfDay)
                status = false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    return status;
}
```

The data comes in as DateTime values which is why I have only looked at the 'TimeOfDay' value. The image shows the layout of the CRUD page.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that there are at least 3 overlaps overall or 3 overlaps of the same time period?

Comment: Ah, I mean there the code needs to work with 3 time periods (start and end time). So having 2 periods works but not 3.

Comment: Ok so you have 3 time periods.  Define what you mean by "is overlapping".  Are they overlapping if any 2 of the three overlap?  What you have there checks adjacent items in the list so item 0 against 1 and item 1 against 2 but not 0 against 2.

Comment: Yes overlapping if any two overlap. So if the times were 10-2, 4-5, 1-3. The first and last times overlap

Comment: Ok then you need a double loop.  In the outer loop you have the 1 time period which is then checked against every other time period.  To reduce time you can start the inner loop at the time period right after the outer loops time period (eliminate duplicate checks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually trickier than it seems, as you need to handle time periods that wrap across midnight.

Using some extension methods, you can make it straight forward.

First, determine if a time is between two others:

```
public static bool Between(this TimeSpan aTime, TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime) => (startTime <= endTime) ? (startTime < aTime && aTime < endTime)
                                                                                                                : (startTime < aTime || aTime < endTime);
```

Then create a special version using the `Period` class for the range:

```
public static bool Between(this TimeSpan aTime, Period aPeriod) => aTime.Between(aPeriod.StartTime.TimeOfDay, aPeriod.EndTime.TimeOfDay);
```

Finally create a test for if one range overlaps a second range (note this is asymmetric):

```
public static bool Overlaps(this Period aPeriod, Period bPeriod) => aPeriod.StartTime.TimeOfDay.Between(bPeriod) || aPeriod.EndTime.TimeOfDay.Between(bPeriod);
```

Now go through all the ranges and check if any range overlaps another range:

```
public static bool IsOverLapping(this List<Period> periods) {
    var periodCount = periods.Count;
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < periodCount; ++j1)
        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < periodCount; ++j2)
            if (j1 != j2 && periods[j1].Overlaps(periods[j2]))
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Finally you can use the method in your `ConfigureViewModel` method:

```
public static bool IsOverLapping(ConfigureViewModel viewModel)
{
    bool status = false;
    var times = viewModel.Periods.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime.TimeOfDay).ToList();
    return times.IsOverLapping();
}
```

Comment: Getting a few errors in that code. Section one works. Section two error one between (TimeSpan has no definition of between). Same error on the two lines below. https://imgur.com/a/u5W1r
Thanks so far for the effort you put in so far

Comment: @JoshFletcher The first two methods are [`Extension Methods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for the `TimeSpan` class. They must exist in a different, static class.

Comment: You could optimize the loops like this: `for (int j1 = 0; j1 < periodCount - 1; ++j1)
        for (int j2 = j1 + 1; j2 < periodCount; ++j2)`. Otherwise you will be comparing each pairing twice (`a.Overlaps(b)` and `b.Overlaps(a)`)

Comment: As I pointed out, the `Overlaps` test is asymmetrical - consider the pairing 3:00 - 15:30 overlaps 15:16 - 15:20 (no) but 15:16 - 15:20 overlaps 3:00 - 15:30 (yes). This could be fixed by testing all possibilities between a pair, but I am not sure that would be faster.

Comment: In fact, the number of comparisons should end up equal either way.

Comment: Thanks @NetMage for the help. I think i understand what you mean Rufus of a different class. Is this correct? https://imgur.com/a/ZCcWb. Getting an error on Overlaps (Period doesnt contain definitions of overlaps) and on IsOverLapping (List<Period> doesn't contain definition of isOverLapping. Thanks team

Comment: I had a typo in `Overlaps` - add `this` before the first parameter, and move the `IsOverlapping(this List<Period> periods)` into the public static class.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thanks for explaining it slow enough for me to understand. All working now so much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be simpler than it sounds. If you have period1 and period2, they are NOT overlapping if period1.Start > period2.End or if period1.End < period2.Start. If neither of these are true, then we know that they are overlapping:

I made this a static method on the `Period` class:

```
public class Period
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public static bool AreOverlapping(Period first, Period second)
    {
        if (first == null || second == null) return false;

        // These two conditions define "overlapping" and must be true
        return first.StartTime <= second.EndTime &&
               first.EndTime >= second.StartTime;
    }
}
```

Then this should simplify the logic in your method that detects if there are any overlapping periods in a group:

```
public static bool DoAnyOverlap(List<Period> periods)
{
    if (periods == null || periods.Count < 2) return false;

    var ordered = periods.OrderBy(p => p.StartTime).ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < ordered.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (Period.AreOverlapping(ordered[i], ordered[i + 1])) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

If for some reason you cannot modify the `Period` class, the logic can easily be incorporated into the `DoAnyOverlap` method:

```
public static bool DoAnyOverlap(List<Period> periods)
{
    if (periods == null || periods.Count < 2) return false;

    var ordered = periods.Where(p => p != null).OrderBy(p => p.StartTime).ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < ordered.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (ordered[i].StartTime <= ordered[i + 1].EndTime &&
            ordered[i].EndTime >= ordered[i + 1].StartTime)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var periods = new[]
{
    new { start = TimeSpan.Parse("10:00"), end = TimeSpan.Parse("14:00") },
    new { start = TimeSpan.Parse("16:00"), end = TimeSpan.Parse("17:00") },
    new { start = TimeSpan.Parse("13:00"), end = TimeSpan.Parse("15:00") },
};

bool overlapping =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, periods.Length)
        .SelectMany(i =>
            Enumerable
                .Range(i + 1, periods.Length - i - 1),
                    (i, j) => new { A = periods[i], B = periods[j] })
        .Any(x => !(x.B.start >= x.A.end || x.B.end <= x.A.start));
```

It'll work with `DateTime` too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ConfigureViewModel` class looks like that:

```
class ConfigureViewModel
{
    ...
    public List<Period> Periods { get; set; }
}

class Period
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

You can use **Time Period Library for .NET:**

> PM> Install-Package TimePeriodLibrary.NET

And `IsOverLapping` mathod may look as simple as that:

```
public static bool IsOverLapping(ConfigureViewModel vm, int numberOfOverlaps)
{
    var ranges = vm.Periods.Select(q => new TimeRange(q.StartTime, q.EndTime));
    TimePeriodCollection periodCollection = new TimePeriodCollection(ranges);
    TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange> intersector = new TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange>();
    return intersector.IntersectPeriods(periodCollection).Count > numberOfOverlaps;
}
```